# OS X 10.8.3: how do I get it to remember my finder windows when I reboot?

Tags: macos

I've looked all over for this, but with "windows" being a major OS name, it's pretty hard to search for this issue. :(

Comment: Feel free to edit in details to explain how the linked question doesn't solve your issue and we'd be happy to re-examine it and re-open it if needed. It will help with search terms in the mean time

Comment: No, that's a duplicate. I read through 7 pages of search hits here, and didn't come across that. Search-fu failure. :( Is it better if I delete this?

Comment: No worries at all, if you edit in the search terms you used - we will get a hit for those exact terms for the next person :-) Closed questions serve a very useful function here since they get indexed by google and lead to the real answers most of the time.

Comment: "osx remember finder windows" were the words I searched for here, so they're already in the question title there. :)